# Create image library

Tags: inkscape

I would like to save some symbols that I have drawn in inkscape in some "homemade" library so that I can drag and drop these image later.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom entries to the 'Symbol set' drop-down in the 'Object → Symbols...' panel by saving .svg files containing symbol definitions in a special directory.

Open the preferences, go to 'System' and check the 'User symbols' input to get its location or click the 'open' button to open it in your file browser directly.

Simply open a new file, add some objects, convert them to symbols by clicking the 'Add Symbol from the current document' button while the 'Current document' symbol set is selected. Finally save your .svg into the folder mentioned above.

To give your symbol sets names (displayed in the drop-down), open the document properties, switch to the 'Metadata' tab and enter a name into the 'Title' input before saving.

You can also give your symbols names (shown when hovering over it in the symbols panel) by opening the 'Object → Object properties...' panel, entering a name into the 'Title' input and then clicking the 'Set' button at the bottom, before converting your object to a symbol. If you want to have multiple objects in one symbol with a name, you need to group them first and set the title on the group.

[image: Symbol panel with example symbol set and symbols]